# Changing the Overlay background color of sweet alert 2

Tags: javascript, sweetalert2

I have recently moved sweet alert 1 to sweet alert 2, but based on the documentation there is no option for theming the overlay background of an alert box like sweet alert 1

```
.swal-overlay {
  background-color: rgba(43, 165, 137, 0.45);
}.
```

Please how can I achieve changing the overlay background of sweet alert 2?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve this you can just use jQuery selectors and select the overlay element like so.

```
<button type="button" onclick="opentheSwal();">OK</button>
<script>
    function opentheSwal() {
        swal(
            'Good job!',
            'You clicked the button!',
            'success'
        );
        $(".swal2-modal").css('background-color', '#000');//Optional changes the color of the sweetalert 
        $(".swal2-container.in").css('background-color', 'rgba(43, 165, 137, 0.45)');//changes the color of the overlay
    }
</script>
```

You will have to select the `.swal2-container.in` to change the overlay and apply the css using jqueries `.css()` function.

Good Luck.

Answer (score 6):

```
Swal.fire({
  icon: 'success',
  background: 'red',
})
```

Comment: Thank you for contributing an answer. Would you kindly edit your answer to to include an explanation of your code? That will help future readers better understand what is going on, and especially those members of the community who are new to the language and struggling to understand the concepts.

Comment: I am not so sure about this. This could change the alert body color but not the overlay color right?

Answer (score 2):

I had this same issue, and found it was necessary to add `!important`to the CSS:

```css
.swal2-container.swal2-backdrop-show, .swal2-container.swal2-noanimation {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.95)!important;
}
```