# Removing darker/grey background from SweetAlert

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert

```js
$( document ).ready(function() {
    Swal.fire({
                              position: 'top-end',
                              title: 'Error!',
                              text: 'Do you want to continue',
                              icon: 'error',
                              confirmButtonText: 'Cool'
                          })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@9"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Is there anyway I can run a sweet alert without getting the background darker while the pop up is on ? Like a Toastr ..
I've already tried to do some research and already tried backroundColor but won't work.

[image: Example]

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47006496/10945464

Comment: `.swal2-container.swal2-backdrop-show {
    background: rgba(0,0,0,.4);
}`

Comment: Try adding `backdrop: false,` to the options, I think it's what you're looking for

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Adding:`backdrop: false,` to options solved the problem.